# It's possible to get a attribute from NSEntityDescription using a NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, key

Im getting the value of an attribute using NSEntityDescription.attributeName, like this:

```
NSEntityDescription *edCurrentRecord = [maListRecords objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UILabel *lblCell = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 10.0, 280, 20.0)];
[lblCell setText:edCurrentRecord.name];
```

There is another way to do this using an NSString? like:

```
NSEntityDescription *edCurrentRecord = [maListRecords objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UILabel *lblCell = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 10.0, 280, 20.0)];
[lblCell setText:[edCurrentRecord someOtherWay:@"usingThisString"]];
```

I looked in the documentation and didn't find an answer and couldn't imagine one too (im new to core data).

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html). The `someOtherWay:` method is actually called `valueForKey:`.